# Files missing in bin folder when publishing ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publishing

I have to release a website developed by a developer which has recently left the company.  I'm struggling to get it to publish using VS2012 publish functionality.  My publish method is 'File System'.  Seems like it writes the files to a folder called bin.  Problem is that not all the files are put there. In VS they show with a yellow warning icon.  Even if I put them there manually they seem to be deleted every time I try to publish again.

There is a file called packages.config and a folder called packages (not in my project, but on the same level as my project).  Some of the missing files are in there.  I'm not quite sure how this is suppose to be helping/used.  Someone might explain that to me?

In case it helps, here is the list of missing files:

- Dapper.pdb &.xml
- Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll & xml
- Microsoft.Data.OData.dll & xml
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity (x2 dll & xml)
- Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.dll
- Newtonsoft.Json.dll & xml
- System.Net.Http.Formatting (dll & xml)
- System.Web.Helpers (dll & xml)
- System.Web.Http.Odata  (dll & xml)
- System.Web.Http.Tracing  (dll & xml)
- System.Web.Http.Webhost (dll & xml)
- System.Web.Http.xml
- System.Web.Mvc.xml
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor (dll & xml)
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment (dll & xml)

References to the above are included in the project.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The packages.config and packages directory would relate to nuGet.
It may be that you need to do a nuGet update on your local VS project in order to get these missing dlls back.
Have a look at the nuGet documentation, and try a `nuget restore` from the command line.